# Dutch hyphenation patterns in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I've been familiarizing myself with LaTeX in the past few weeks. It is awesome, but I ran into one problem I just can't manage to fix...

Sometimes, I want to produce reports in Dutch, using LaTeX. Most of it works (dates and such), but I can't seem to get the proper hyphenation patterns loaded... Every time I compile, it returns a warning (without failing to compile, though):

*Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for
(babel) the language `Dutch'
(babel) I will use the patterns loaded for \language=0 instead.*

So it uses the default (English) hyphenation. It hasn't been much of a bother yet, as it is not too hard to use some padding words, but I imagine it might turn into a problem at some point. I even found out that our handout for Calculus probably encountered the same issue - its hyphenation is plain wrong.

I did some Googling and noticed that more people seem to have the problem, and some manage to fix it, some don't. I belong to the last group. I tried adding the language to language.dat and having fmtutil recompile all configurations, but still no luck. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: what latex are you using?

Comment: version or type? It's pdflatex, but I tried latex'ing it to dvi, same result...

Answer (score 1):

There is a question on this in the [TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=newlang). It notes to make sure that after modifying `language.dat` to have the line for your language uncommented, you should also make sure that the file name in there is correct. Otherwise it looks like you're doing all the things mentioned there, like running `fmtutil`, so I don't know what else could be wrong.